# MVC Pattern: Where does formatting/processing type work belong? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, cocoa-design-patterns

As my Cocoa skills gradually improve I'm trying not to abuse the MVC as I did early on when I'd find myself backed into a hole built by my previous assumptions. I don't have anyone here to bounce this off of so hoping one of you can help...

I have a custom Model class that has numerous & varied properties (NSString, NSDate, NSNumber, etc.). I have a need to serialize the properties for transmission. Occasionally as this data is being processed for serialization a questions may come up that the user will need to respond to (UIAlertView, etc.)

Without bogging down in too many more specifics where does this code belong?

- Part of me says **Model** because it's about persistence of data - in a way.
- Part of me says **View** because it's another interpretation of the core data (no pun intended) contained within the model. And the user will have to interact with dialogs on occasion as data is processed
- Part of me says **Controller** because it's managing the transformation of data between model & view.

Is it a combination of all three? If so how would communication be handled between classes as the data is being processed? NSNotifications? Direct method calls?

Answer (score 1):

This may be something that you'd want to use the Visitor pattern for -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern -- because you might eventually want to use different sorts of serialization for different things and you can have different visitor classes rather than a lot of special cases in the model code.

Here's a discussion of the Visitor pattern in objective-c/cocoa: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?VisitorPattern

Here's an (old!!!) article from Dr. Dobbs about the visitor pattern in objective-c: http://www.drdobbs.com/184410252

The reason that the problem you're working on doesn't fit well into the MVC paradigm is that the serialization that you're doing is like a view on a stream-based rendering surface and it is displayed.  Sometimes, this can be done really smoothly in the model but sometimes it's more complex and you need to look at your case to figure out which one it is.

Frequently, the transmission/web service (or whatever) code you're using will have its own handler for this data, for example [ObjectiveResource](http://iphoneonrails.com/) adds a serialization and deserialization  handler that works as an extension to NSObject that enables it to do a lot of this stuff transparently, and you might look into that code (particularly the ObjectiveSupport part) if you're trying to do this more generically.

Answer (score 0):

Typically almost all application specific code belongs in the controller. The controller should interact and observe (via notification) the model and update the view as appropriate.

If you are doing model processing such that it is something that might be re-used in another app with the same model, then that processing could be in the model.

Views can be laid out in Interface Builder or created in code and/or be subclassed for custom drawing, but they should not have application logic and would not interact directly with the model.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the serialising code in the model. If the process fails it can report that to whatever's listening to it (the view / controller) which can then present the UIAlertView, correct the problem and re-submit for another attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say in the model.

The call to serialize the data will be done by the controller. If the data cannot be serialized then the model should return an error which the controller then has to handle.